# Nesting rows in zurb Foundation grid

Tags: css, responsive-design, frameworks, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I am new to working with Zurb Foundation 5. I am trying to build a complex header bar using the columns and rows. However, I want to use nested rows within a main row.

Is this possible with Foundation grid system? I'm confused on how to order the divs.

I linked to the code I've tried however, I can't get that second row to nest properly.

what I want to do:
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/qv6z59w4/        <--- what I tried to do

```
<div class="row empty">
  <div class="a column small-12 large-3 center panel">A</div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="b column small-6 medium-3 large-2 panel">B
    </div>
    <div class="b column small-6 medium-3 large-2 panel">B
    </div>
    <div class="b column small-6 medium-3 large-2 panel">B
    </div>
    <div class="b column small-6 medium-3 large-2 panel">B
    </div>
    <div class="c column hide-for-medium-down large-1 panel">
      <ul>
        <li class="icon">C</li>
        <li class="icon">C</li>
        <li class="icon">C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="d column hide-for-small large-centered large-6 panel">D
    </div>
    <div class="e column small-12 large-2 panel">E
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div { text-align: center; }

.a { background-color: red; }
.b { background-color: blue; }
.c { background-color: green; }
.n { background-color: yellow; }
.r { background-color: orange; }
.m { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/5.4.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="a large-3 small-12 columns">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="b large-8 small-12 columns">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="r large-3 columns">1
            </div>   
            <div class="r large-3 columns">2
            </div>   
            <div class="r large-3 columns">3
            </div>   
            <div class="r large-3 columns">4
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="n large-8 columns">6
            </div>
            <div class="m large-4 columns">7
            </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c large-1 small-6 columns">
    C
  </div>
</div>
```

Or have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qv6z59w4/1/)

Have a row with `column-3`, `column-8` spanned for middle section of the header and `column-1` and nest the middle section with the appropriate columns.

P.S: check the fullpage view of the snippet

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. So basically, you define the main row first where all the content needs to fit into. Then you move column by column and nest rows within those vertical sections.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant or it doesn't work anymore. No connection to the image in the question.

Comment: @emrah it works..you can see the fiddle in full screen and it looks the same as screenshot above..